# Salesforce google charts group by aggregate query not pulling appropriate results

Tags: apex, group-by, aggregateresult, google-charts

```
Set<Id> realBy = new Set<Id>();                                      
for (Projects__c vP1 : [SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Id, Total_Value__c FROM Proj_Upd__r
                        WHERE Rep_End__c >= :dd1 
                        AND Rep_End__c  <= :dd2 
                        ORDER BY Rep_End__c DESC NULLS LAST, Name DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1) 
                        FROM Projects__c 
                        WHERE Status__c != 'Cancelled' 
                        AND Status__c != 'Rejected' 
                        AND Acc__c IN: AccSets]) 
{
    for (Proj_Upd__c pu1 : vP1.Proj_Upd__r) {
        realBy.add(pu1.id);
    }
}
System.debug('=====Month1+=++=='+realBy); 

AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [Select SUM(Total_Value__c) sum1,  calendar_year(Rep_End__c) yearVal, calendar_month(Rep_End__c ) monVal 
                           FROM Proj_Upd__c WHERE Id IN: realBy      
                           GROUP BY calendar_year(Rep_End__c ), calendar_month(Rep_End__c ) 
                           ORDER BY calendar_year(Rep_End__c ), calendar_month(Rep_End__c )];

for (AggregateResult g9 : groupedResults) {
    wrapData AccountSumTemp = new wrapData();
    AccountSumTemp.PeriodVal = myMonths2.get(integer.valueof(g9.get('monVal'))) + ' ' + string.valueof(g9.get('yearVal')) ;
    AccountSumTemp.NetValue = integer.valueof(g9.get('sum1'));
    AccountSumTemp.RowType = 'ValbyDate';
    contentList.add(AccountSumTemp);
}
```

The above query is to Pull the Total_Value__c by considering Rep_End__c date, it should pull the data as per the time frame input given, for example if input is given as 2016 to 2016 Rep_End__c values, it should pull all the updates which are made between in this year, so the first query to pulling around 6 results

```
id: aaa, bbbb, cccc, ddd, eee, fff
```

and where as the aggregate results should pull in same values but it is pulling only 4, i.e aaa, ccc, ddd, fff where as bbbb and eee have same ending date (2/2/2016)

seems to be some issue on Group By, please let me know what wrong am I doing here? I did tested by changing the month it works, once the dates are changed to same dates second query doesn't pull the appropriate data

Comment: I suspect the root of your issue may be related to the subquery you're using in the previous query the problematice query relies on where you have `ORDER BY Rep_End__c DESC NULLS LAST, Name DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1`. Using `LIMIT 1` makes no sense to me with an `ORDER BY` clause and I wouldn't expect it to return the results you're expecting.

Comment: Proj_Upd__c is a child obj and I am trying to pull the most updated rep_end__c date and limit one is helping in sorting the values and just pull the most recent update made in a given time stamp, for example in 2016 there are be multiple updates in every quarter, and the values are perfectly captured in ORDER BY Rep_End__c DESC NULLS LAST, Name DESC NULLS LAST LIMIT 1, but in aggregate while grouping its not considering projects with same dates just pulling anyone.